# Regex to detect only single back slash and replace with double

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

My function gets a network path from various places.

Some people send the right path as:

> \\\\127.0.0.1\\Folder1\\Folder2\\File.txt

But Some don't. They send :

> \\127.0.0.1\Folder1\Folder2\File.txt

As my code is in VB.It does nor cause an issue. I have to send this further to a API which is in C# and it throws error in second case.

Now, I want the second type of path to be converted to first. But If the path is in first format already, don't do anything.

If I replace \ with \\ it will change the first type of path to:

> \\\\\\\\127.0.0.1\\\\Folder1\\\\Folder2\\\\File.txt

Which should not happen. The conversion should only happen when there's single slash in path.

What can be done?

Comment: `\\{1}` should work. An escape is needed as `\` is a special character in regex.

Comment: @PawełŁukasik this will be true for two slashes too. It should be true only for single character.

Comment: Right, what about sth like `[^\\]+(\\{1})`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [IO.Path.GetFullPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfullpath?view=netcore-3.1) to normalize the path:

```
Dim p = "\\\\127.0.0.1\\Folder1\\Folder2\\File.txt"
Dim q = IO.Path.GetFullPath(p)
Console.WriteLine(q)
```

Outputs:

```
\\\127.0.0.1\Folder1\Folder2\File.txt
```

So now you have a consistent starting point - except for the triple-backslash, which I could find no reference to in [File path formats on Windows systems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats?view=netcore-3.1).

So finally,

```
Dim q = IO.Path.GetFullPath(p).Replace("\\\", "\\").Replace("\", "\\")
```

gives

```
\\\\127.0.0.1\\Folder1\\Folder2\\File.txt
```

even for an input of `\\127.0.0.1\Folder1\Folder2\File.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't want to use Regex, give this a try:

```
Dim path As String = "\\127.0.0.1\Folder1\Folder2\File.txt"

If Not path.StartsWith("\\\\") Then path = path.Replace("\", "\\")
```

Comment: For now we have done this. But it's a Jugaad. I want something technical and firm.